# Binding jQuery lightBox to dynamically added images

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the jQuery lightbox plugin on my page which has multiple image carousel . My requirement is that I need to apply the lightbox on individual images which I currently accomplish by writing

```
$(a#lightboxrotator).each({ $(this).lightBox();});
```

This works fine but my problem is that I want to add carousels dynamically . Is there some way I can use the Jquery 'on' for custom functions in plugins the same way built in handlers are used ? Something like

```
$('body).on('a#lightboxrotator','click',fn())
```

can be used with lightbox ?

Comment: Have a look at the help for on() you have the parameters the wrong way around -> http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: ID's must be unique in apage..so you have a structural problem right from the start, change ID to class on each of the repeating ID's

Answer (score 0):

Per my comment above...ID's must be unique

on() and other delegation methods are ideal for event handlers but with plugins that are more involved you need to re-initialize them on new html you insert...after it is inserrted. In the case of your lightbox it attaches handlers internally from plugin code, so you really can't mimic that with your own click handler

Assuming you are ajax loading the new html, you would use success callback of ajax to call the same code you already use on page load

```
$(a.lightboxrotator).lightBox();
```